# Add class to give element on page load with document.body.classList.add

Tags: javascript, class, load

Please help me to convert this code to work on page load in stead of on click

```
 p.setup = () => {
      playBtn = document.querySelector('#play-btn')
      playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.body.classList.add('start-anim')
          audio.loop()
      })
```

I tried this:

```
 p.setup = () => {
       document.addEventListener('load', () => {
        document.body.classList.add('start-anim')
          audio.loop()
      })
```

Chrome says `The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page`

Comment: I've never seen an `audio.loop` method, just a boolean.  What is `p.setup`, besides a `function` that I don't see you calling? Look at your inspector. Do you see that your HTML has `<body class="start-anim">`? If you want the HTML class attribute on another Element, then use another Element.

Comment: hi, thanks for your attention . i want to use this on my website soruce code is from there https://tympanus.net/codrops/2020/02/24/audio-based-image-distortion-effects-with-webgl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the following (JavaScript):

```js
function doSomething(){
    console.log("body onload");
}
```

```html
<body onload="doSomething()">
<p> test </p>
</body>
```

Or you can use jQuery with this:

```js
// jquery .ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("jquery document ready");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```